# Fetch not out-putting all data to Google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, fetch

I am using Fetch to out-put JSON data to google sheets

The Fetch function is not outputting all the data in the JSON to the sheet

Here is what I get when I run my Fetch function
[image]

But here is what it should be if it were adding all the data in the JSON
[image]

You can see that columns `N` through `R` are not being added to the sheet

Here is my Fetch function

```
function fetchData() {
  // Set Fetch Variables
  var url = "https://sum-app.net/projects/13435720200118544/download_data/combined_json"
  var response     = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var responseText = response.getContentText();
  var responseJson = JSON.parse(responseText); 

  var connectionKeys = Object.keys(responseJson.connections[0]); 
  var data = responseJson.connections.map(e => connectionKeys.map(f => {
      return e[f] instanceof Array ? e[f].join("|") : e[f];
  })); 
  data.unshift(connectionKeys);
  data = data.map(x => x.map(y => typeof y === 'undefined' || null ? "" : y));

  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.clearContents();//clear sheet
  sh.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);//load the data
}
```

Here is the JSON:
`https://sum-app.net/projects/13435720200118544/download_data/combined_json`

If it is helpful here is a Google sheet with the Fetch function
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CuP2DDO-rB1henrMAurBgb-CYmh7RNBbSHOjF6BqG5c/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you in advance for any assistance with getting the `fetchData` function to output all the data in the JSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I suggest is to replace

```
var connectionKeys = Object.keys(responseJson.connections[0]);
```

by

```
  let myDico = new Map()
  responseJson.connections.forEach(function(key){
    Object.keys(key).forEach(function(item){
       myDico.set(item,'')
    })
  })
  var connectionKeys = []
  myDico.forEach(function(value, key) {
    connectionKeys.push(key)
  })
```